# SFP Uplinks from Cisco WS-C2960S-24TS-L to Non-SFP Ports

Tags: cisco, switch, sfp

Our department recently purchased new WS-C2960S-24TS-L switches to act as our cabinet switches.  However, these will be uplinked into existing WS-2960S-24TS-L that act as the aggregation switches.

What are our options for connecting these switches together?  The uplinks on the cabinet switches are SFP while the ports on the aggregate switches are normal RJ-45 gig-e ports.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are copper gig SFP modules.  They typically do not support auto crossover or negotiation for 100mb / 10mb links, but if you're connecting to a gig capable copper port on the other end it won't be an issue.

An example of  such a beast is: http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/default.aspx?edc=2222913

Comment: +1 SPF is a standard interface that allows you to pick the media (RJ45, SPF direct, Fiber, etc). You just need a SPF Module that converts to RJ45, plug in a standard Ethernet cable and off you go.